# React Hook Form - Errors not working for multiple forms on a single page for react hook form v7.5.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form

For the Previous versions of react hook form, multiple forms used to work if you created another form object with the following lines of code:

```
    const { 
    register: register2,
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,
    errors: errors2
  } = useForm()
```

Now with the syntax changed to formState the errors object for the second form is not getting created, and it throws an error.

```
const { 
    register: register2,
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,
    formState: { errors2 } 
  } = useForm()
```

My Complete Code is here:

```
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { useState } from 'react'
function App() {

  const [firstname,setFirstName] = useState(null)
  const [lastname,setLastName] = useState(null)
  const [email,setEmail] = useState(null)
  const [address,setAddress] = useState(null)
  const { register, handleSubmit , formState: { errors } } = useForm()
  const { 
    register: register2,
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,
    formState: { errors2 } 
  } = useForm()

  const handleInputChange = (e) =>{

        const target = e.target
        const name = target.name

        if(name === 'firstname'){
          setFirstName(target.value)
        }
        if(name === 'lastname'){
          setLastName(target.value)
        }
        if(name === 'email'){
          setEmail(target.value)
        }
        if(name === 'address'){
          setAddress(target.value)
        }


  }

  const submitData = async()=>{

      console.log(firstname,lastname)

  }
  const submitData2 = async()=>{

    console.log(email,address)

}
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form key={1} onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitData)}>
        <input name='firstname' type="text" {...register('firstname',{required:true})} onChangeCapture={handleInputChange} placeholder="enter firstname" />
        <p>{errors.firstname && "First Name is Required"}</p>
        <input name='lastname' type="text"{...register('lastname',{required:true})} onChangeCapture={handleInputChange}  placeholder="enter lastname" />
        <p>{errors.lastname && "Last Name is Required"}</p>
        <button type="submit"> submit </button>
      </form>
      <hr />
      <form key={2} onSubmit={handleSubmit2(submitData2)}>
      <input name='email' type="text" {...register2('email',{required:true})} onChangeCapture={handleInputChange} placeholder="enter firstname" />
      <p>{errors.email && " Email is Required"}</p>
      <input name='address' type="text"{...register2('address',{required:true})} onChangeCapture={handleInputChange}  placeholder="enter lastname" />
      <p>{errors.address && "Address is Required"}</p>
      <button type="submit"> submit </button>
    </form>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And this is my Output Screenshot:
[image]

The Errors get triggered for the first form, but for the second form, the errors don't display. react hook v7.5.2
Please Help !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the way you destructure the `formState`. Try this way and it should work:

```js
const { 
    register: register2,
    handleSubmit: handleSubmit2,
    formState: { errors: errors2 } 
  } = useForm()
```

Comment: I changed my code from `const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm()` to `const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm()` and the second one worked, can someone explain why is that? @knoefel

Comment: The first one is the syntax from v6, the second one is the newer and current syntax starting from v7.